# Deriving mean and variance of a function of Gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose $\mathbb{G}$ is a tight zero mean Gaussian process and $F$ is an absolutely continuous CDF

$$Y=\int_a^b\frac{d\mathbb{G}}{1-F}+\int_a^b\frac{\mathbb{G} \, dF}{(1-F)^2}$$

I know that $Y$ is a normal random variable. However, the question is how do I derive its mean and variance?

Thank's!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: @stats134711: Actually, in my case $\mathbb{G}$ is the limit of an empirical process ($F$ is the underlying true CDF). So the expression simplifies to

$$\frac{\mathbb{B}(F(b))}{1-F(b)}-\frac{\mathbb{B}(F(a))}{1-F(a)}\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$

where $\mathbb{B}$ is the Brownian bridge and 

$$\sigma^2=\frac{F(b)}{1-F(b)}-\frac{F(a)}{1-F(a)}$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you simply the the variance of the second expression regarding the integration of $\mathbb{G}$ w.r.t F? Isn't it a double integral of the covariance of $\mathbb{G}$?

Comment: @stats134711: I mean that $Y$ equals to that expression (you can verify this by assuming that $\mathbb{G}$ is non-random and integrating the expression).